# jquery quantity 1 or more

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery:

```
if($('div.ProductNameText').text()=='Product1')
{
$("#kitProduct #Quantity").attr("value", "1");
}
```

But i want it so that if it finds Product1 then it allows the customer to enter more than 1.

I am overriding the previous jquery which sets it to 25 because that checks if its a kit product.

Here is the kit product code:

```
function KitOptionsChanged() {
            // Get total of selected index... if this is above 0 at least 1 dropdown option has been changed
            var totals = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < $('select.selitemoption').length; i++) {
                totals += $("select.selitemoption").eq(i).attr("selectedIndex");
            }
            if (totals == 0) {
                // No dropdowns changed from defaults - check textbox
                if ($("#kitProduct #KitFormOptions textarea").val() == "") {
                    // Min value doesn't need to be 25... do i need to anything here?
                } else {
                    //Check current
                    if (parseInt($("#kitProduct #Quantity").val()) < 25) {
                        // If it is less than 25 then set it to 25
                        $("#kitProduct #Quantity").attr("value", "25");
                    }

                    if($('div.ProductNameText').text()=='This is product ABC'){
                        $("#kitProduct #Quantity").attr("value", "1");
                        }
                }
            }
            else {
                // At least 1 index has been changed... set min total to 25.
                if (parseInt($("#kitProduct #Quantity").val()) < 25) {
                    $("#kitProduct #Quantity").attr("value", "25");
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT:added the quantity box html:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4" size="3" onkeyup="if(typeof(getShipping) == 'function'){getShipping()}" onchange="if(typeof(getShipping) == 'function'){getShipping()}" id="Quantity" name="Quantity" value="1">
```

Comment: Can I see your html for that? It would help me to understand from where you want to get product's quantity for customer.

Comment: The HTML for the quantity box is now showing in the original post.

Comment: the HTML is not really needed as i just need to change the quantity box to 1 or more. As the the javascript is ran line by line i would be overriding the 25 quantity.

Comment: Sorry I still couldn't understand how you want to allow the customer to enter more than one product. Perhaps you want to not change the `#Quantity` to 25 if < than 25 when it finds the Product1?

Comment: the kit product code cannot change. The jqeury needs to simply check if Product1 exists in the div class content and then set the quantity to 1 or MORE

Answer (score 0):

Well you can see how many times Product1 matches inside the div and the count should give you the quantity of items like this:

```
quantity = $('div.ProductNameText').text().match(/Product1/g).length;
if(quantity)
{
    $("#kitProduct #Quantity").attr("value", quantity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if the user wants 3, the code will just apply 1 to the quantity.. that would be incorrect. Any ideas?

Comment: If the user adds 3 Product1 at the div, it would apply 3 on quantity. I don't know how the "adding products inside the div" process works.

Comment: the page loads, it checks the div and changed the quantity textbox to 1.. the user wants to change the value to 3. Then the user clicks add to cart.

Comment: Oh, so he can have 3 div.ProductNameText with Product1 inside?

Comment: Sorry I think I wont know how to help you. There is too little information. I would say if you want to find a way for the user to increase quantity number, just add an input text with quantity, that using the information I have with me.